# Set a dynamic fee based on custom checkout radio buttons and text field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, woocommerce

I am trying to create a custom checkout radio button that calculates restaurant tip in percentage.

For the radio button, the static value is working fine.

However, I want to get the subtotal and calculate certain percentage on custom radio button click.

This is my code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_box_option_to_checkout' );
function add_box_option_to_checkout( $checkout ) {

$chosen = WC()->session->get( 'tip' );
    $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? WC()->checkout->get_value( 'tip' ) : $chosen;
    $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? '0' : $chosen;
    
    $total = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
$fivetip = $total * 0.05;

    woocommerce_form_field( 'tip',  array(
        'type'      => 'radio',
        'class'     => array( 'form-row-wide', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
        'options'   => array(
            $fivetip  => '5%',
            '10.00'     => '10%',
            '15.00'     => '15%',
        ),
    ), $chosen );
    
        woocommerce_form_field( 'add_tip', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('add_tipform-row-wide'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter Custom Tip Amount') 
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'add_tip' ));
    
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'checkout_tip_fee', 20, 1 );
function checkout_tip_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( $radio = WC()->session->get( 'tip' ) ) {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Tip', $radio );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'checkout_tip_choice_to_session' );

function checkout_tip_choice_to_session( $posted_data ) {
    parse_str( $posted_data, $output );
    if ( isset( $output['tip'] ) ){
        WC()->session->set( 'tip', $output['tip'] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is something advanced using **Ajax and WC Sessions**:

It will add a custom a tip (as a custom fee) based on selected radio buttons options: fixed percentages options or custom option that will show a text field to allow customer to input a fixed amount.

Displayed Fields are hand coded to get a better display than WooCommerce form fields for radio buttons *(see the screenshots below).*

[image]

**How it works for the customer:**

On checkout page load, a Tip of 5% *(a fee)* is applied *(selected by default)*. When changing the selected option to something else, the applied fee changes.

If the "custom" option is selected, the fee is removed while a text field appears below:

[image]
Customer can input **a fixed amount** and a Tip *(a fee)* is applied with this amount.

**Here is the code:**

```
// Display custom checkout fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_box_option_to_checkout' );
function add_box_option_to_checkout( ) {
    // Here set your radio button options (Values / Labels pairs)
    $options = array( '5'  => '5%', '10' => '10%', '15' => '15%', 'custom' => __('Custom', 'woocommerce') );

    // Radio button fields
    echo '<style> #add_tip_field.form-row label { display:inline-block; margin-left:6px; } </style>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="add_tip_field"><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
    <label for="add_tip"><strong>'.__('Add a tip', 'woocommerce'). ':</strong>&nbsp;</label>';

    foreach ( $options as $value => $label_name ) {
        $checked = $value == '5' ? ' checked="checked"' : '';

        echo '<label for="add_tip_'.$value.'" class="radio ">
            <input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="'.$value.'" name="add_tip" id="add_tip_'.$value.'"'.$checked.'>&nbsp'.$label_name.'
        </label>';
    }
    echo '</span></p>';

    // Text field (hidden by default)
    echo '<p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="custom_tip_field" style="display:none""><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="input-text " name="custom_tip" id="custom_tip" value="" placeholder="'.__('Input a tip amount', 'woocommerce').'">
    </span></p>';
}

// jQuery / Ajax script
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'wc_checkout_fee_script' );
function wc_checkout_fee_script() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        var addTip    = 'input[name="add_tip"]',
            customTip = 'input[name="custom_tip"]'

        function triggerAjaxEvent( amount, type = 'percent' ){
           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'tip_fee',
                    'amount': amount,
                    'type'  : type
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                    console.log(result);
                },
            });
        }

        triggerAjaxEvent( $(addTip+':checked').val() );

        $('form.checkout').on('change', addTip, function() {
            var textField = $('#custom_tip_field'),
                percent   = $(this).val();

            if( percent === 'custom' && textField.css('display') === 'none' ) {
                textField.show(200);
            } else if ( percent !== 'custom' && textField.css('display') !== 'none' ) {
                textField.hide(200, function(){
                    $(customTip).val('');
                });
            }
            triggerAjaxEvent( percent );
        });

        $('form.checkout').on('input change', customTip, function() {
            triggerAjaxEvent( $(this).val(), 'custom' );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Get Ajax request and save data to WC session
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tip_fee', 'get_tip_fee' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_tip_fee', 'get_tip_fee' );
function get_tip_fee() {
    if ( isset($_POST['amount']) && isset($_POST['type']) ) {
        $fee  = is_numeric($_POST['amount']) && $_POST['amount'] > 0 ? floatval($_POST['amount']) : 0;

        WC()->session->set('fee_data', array(
            'type'   => esc_attr($_POST['type']),
            'amount' => $fee
        ) );

        print_r(WC()->session->get('fee_data'));
    }
    die();
}


// Add a dynamic fee from WC Session ajax data
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'checkout_custom_tip_fee' );
function checkout_custom_tip_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return;

    $data = WC()->session->get('fee_data');
    $fee  = $total = 0;

    if ( isset($data['type']) && isset($data['amount']) ) {
        // 1. Fixed Fee amount
        if ( $data['type'] === 'custom' ) {
            $text  = $data['type'];
            $fee   = $data['amount'];
        } 
        // 2. Calculated percentage Fee amount
        elseif ( $data['type'] === 'percent' && $data['amount'] > 0 ) {
            $text  = $data['amount'] . '%';

            // Get cart subtotal excl. Taxes (discounted)
            foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                $total = $cart_item['line_total'];
            }
            // Calculate fee
            $fee   = $total * $data['amount'] / 100 ;
        }
        // Add the fee
        if ( $fee > 0 ) {
            $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __('Tip (%s)', 'woocommerce' ), $text ), $fee );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Addition related to your comment:**

To use cart items total `including` taxes replace in last function:

```
            // Get cart subtotal excl. Taxes (discounted)
            foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                $total = $cart_item['line_total'];
            }
```

with

```
            // Get cart subtotal Incl. Taxes (discounted)
            foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                $total = $cart_item['line_total'] + $cart_item['line_tax'];
            }
```

Comment: I added a value of 0 so that nothing is checked by default. The custom fee is not working as of now. Radio button are working as expected. Thank you so much for your time and effort. It really means a lot to me. I couldn't figure out why the value from the input field is not working. Is it working for you?

Comment: I fixed the text field as well. The custom had to be in small letters in this code.

` if ( $data['type'] === 'custom' ) `

Thank you so much for helping me out. Without your help this would not be possible.

Comment: I am having an issue. The woocommerce session is giving wrong calculation if a user goes back to the online order and adds more items. Looks like, the woocommerce session value has to be unset for the tip because it gets stored and displays in the cart on the right on checkout page when the page gets loaded. But I do not know how to do it and where to add the code. Please help me

Comment: Thank you. It works but the tip percent is incorrect. This is the [link](https://misterindia.kodeonix.com.np/online-order/?523_product_cat%5B0%5D=18&523_device=laptop&523_filtered=true). Only the one with the text box works perfectly. The problem is with the radio buttons.

Comment: I didn't figure where the `'` is. I just replaced my code with yours but the tip percent from the radio buttons is still incorrect. It's alright, you don't have to say sorry. You have given me your time and support and that's a lot. I will clean the comments and upvote your answer later because this question is posted from my other account.

Comment: This is the [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d725e5fedf87d9c2de08d23e32c17e0420210310060904/c3d18d) to my code. I was testing it out that's why it was showing a critical error. I visited your website and what I found out was the tip percent is not correct in yours as well. The subtotal is 20,70. If I click on 10% on the radio button, the tip is 1,80. However, 10% of 20,70 is 2,07 isn't it?

Comment: @RemanBala Ok I get it now… My cart item total calculation was **excluding taxes**… I have added an addition at the end that include taxes on cart item total…

Comment: The tip show be excluded so the first one was fine. When I added a bracket to `($data['amount'] / 100)`. The result is correct only if there is one item in the cart. If there are more than one, the result is incorrect again. The logic is, `tip = subtotal * tipPercent`, but I could not still figure out what is causing the issue. You can have a look at the link of the website I provided above.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it like this:

1. **Add fields** to checkout
2. **Empty**/**deselect** the fields based on the field valued (so as to leave only the radio button or the text field valued)
3. **Calculate the cost** based on the field and add the fee to the cart

So:

```
// add custom fields to checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_box_option_to_checkout' );
function add_box_option_to_checkout( $checkout ) {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'tip',  array(
        'type'    => 'radio',
        'class'   => array( 'form-row-wide', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
        'options' => array(
            '5'  => '5%',
            '10' => '10%',
            '15' => '15%',
        ),
    ));
    
    woocommerce_form_field( 'add_tip', array(
        'type'        => 'text',
        'class'       => array('add_tipform-row-wide', 'update_totals_on_change'),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter Custom Tip Amount') 
    ));

}
```

Now a jQuery script will empty the text field when a radio button is selected and vice versa:

```
// uncheck radio buttons when text field is changed
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'uncheck_radio_buttons_when_text_field_is_changed' );
function uncheck_radio_buttons_when_text_field_is_changed() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // deselect radio buttons when an amount is entered in the text field
    jQuery('#add_tip').keyup(function(){
        jQuery('#tip_field input[name=tip]').prop('checked', false);
    });
    // clears the text field when a percentage is selected
    jQuery('input[name=tip]').change(function(){
        jQuery('#add_tip').val('');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Finally it calculates the amount of the fee based on the selected value **calculated on the subtotal** *(excluding taxes)* of the cart.

> **Make sure you use the same name for the fee** to add to the cart in
> order to overwrite the same and display only one.

```
// adds a custom fee based on the field valued
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_custom_fee', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_fee( $cart ) {

    // get the subtotal (excluding taxes)
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax;

    if ( ! $_POST || is_admin() || ! is_ajax() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['post_data'] ) ) {
        parse_str( $_POST['post_data'], $post_data );
    } else {
        $post_data = $_POST;
    }

    // adds the fee based on the checked percentage
    if ( isset( $post_data['tip'] ) ) {
        $percentage = $post_data['tip'];
        $fee = $subtotal * $percentage / 100;
        if ( $fee > 0 ) {
            WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Tip', $fee, true );
        }
    }

    // adds the fee based on the amount entered
    if ( isset( $post_data['add_tip'] ) ) {
        $fee = (float) str_replace( ',', '.', $post_data['add_tip'] );
        if ( $fee > 0 ) {
            WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Tip', $fee, true );
        }
    }

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. The code is working as expected.